# Enabling dynamic lighting in Roll20, but the dynamic lighting tab is missing

Tags: roll20

Trying to enable dynamic lighting but I'm missing the Dynamic Lighting tab shown in the official tutorial.

My Game:

[image]

The official tutorial:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### It's not a free feature

The [FAQ on dynamic lighting](https://help.roll20.net/hc/en-us/articles/4403860932375-What-s-New-With-Dynamic-Lighting-) makes it very clear that it is a Plus or Pro subscriber feature.

> This page is about Dynamic Lighting, a feature exclusive to Plus and Pro subscribers, or to players in a game created by a subscriber. If you'd like to use this feature, consider upgrading your account.

[image: The FAQ page containing above language]

The feature is also listed only in the two paid tiers, as you can see on the [subscription page](https://app.roll20.net/why-subscribe-to-roll20):

[image: Free: no dynamic lighting; plus ($50 per year): dynamic lighting; pro ($100 per year): dynamic lighting]